# How to remove default RootDN 'admin' in OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, admin, openldap

I setup a LDAP server by using slapd and ldap-utils.

Due to the default RootDN as admin, I hope use other one to replace it.

Use the modify command to replace the default RootDN.

ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ./rootdn.ldif

```
rootdn.ldif
dn:  olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=admintest,dc=testcom
```

But seen default 'admin' still can work by command

```
ldapsearch -x -D cn=admin,dc=testcom -W
```

I already double check the file in /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config.

The olcRootDN in 'olcDatabase={1}mdb.ldif' is the new one(admintest).

Anything wrong with my steps?

Comment: Finally, use command 'ldapdelete' to remove the default 'admin'

Comment: You can use 'slapcat -n 0 | less' to view the configuration database and then search within for what you're trying to delete, to see if it's still there.